# Does this game or similar games exist?

Tags: identify-this-game

Ok, First I have zero  knowledge about boardgames, I browsed some in the past and have watched some youtube videos a while ago and this will seem really , really weird, but today I woke up witha  really vivid dream about a board game, I don't know if I have just made it up or I have seen it being played and that made went into my mind.

The game was like this. the first (darker) rows from each side , were the "teachers" and the second (lighter) the students, I actually remember some rules:

[image]

- Students can move forward 1 circle
- Teachers can stack upon students,
  when student has 1 teacher it can move 1 circle in any direction,
- For each aditional teacher upon a student it can move the amount of
  teachers upon itself: 2 teachers = 2 circles in any direction, 3
  teachers = 3 circles in any direction.
- A piece can only take another
  piece of the same value or below a student can take a student a
  student+1 can take a  student+1 and a student a student+2 can take a 
  student+2 , student+1 and a student
- teachers can't move unless there are no students on the board
  once this happens teachers can be stacked in the same manner as students
- a player loses when there are no more teachers available

I know it may be taken as offtopic, It just seems awfully specific for a dream and is bugging me , so I had to post

Comment: I have a weird question: if a teacher can't move unless there are no students on the board, and the students can only move "forward,", how do the teachers get stacked on top of the students?

Comment: @SocioMatt In this case I think the only move they could make would be stacking up.

But I don't think all the rules here make much sense since they are a recollection from my dream, I just wrote everything I could remember so people could identify this as some real board game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A somewhat similar game to this exists, called DVONN, in which pieces stack onto each other and then a stack can move a number of spaces equal to the number of pieces in the stack.  However, the rest of your game is different and as far as I know is not identical to any currently existing game.